# Terraform: Invalid dynamic for_each value. Cannot use a list of object value in for_each. An iterable collection is required

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-ibm, terraform-loop

Terraform version: "1.2.9"

Terraform fails with invalid value error when input variable with type `list(object({}))` and marked as `sensitive = true` is passed to `dynamic` block with `for_each`.
The error is not seen when the input variable is marked as non-sensitive.

Input variable looks like below:

```
variable "sample_variable" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    description = optional(string)
    secure = optional(bool)
    type = string
    use_default = optional(bool)
    value = string
  }))
  sensitive   = true
  description = "A list of objects with sensitive values."
  default     = []
}
```

And is consumed in a resource `dynamic` block with a `for_each` as shown below:

```
resource "ibm_cloud_sample_resource" "my_resource" {
  name                     = var.name
  description              = var.description
  template_env_settings    = local.env_values
  tags                     = var.tags
  dynamic "template_inputs" {
    for_each = var.sample_variable
    content {
      name        = template_inputs.value.name
      description = template_inputs.value.description
      type        = template_inputs.value.type
      value       = template_inputs.value.value
      secure      = template_inputs.value.secure
      use_default = template_inputs.value.use_default
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value
│
│   on main.tf line 50, in resource "ibm_cloud_sample_resource" "my_resource":
│   50:     for_each = var.sample_variable
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.sample_variable has a sensitive value
│
│ Cannot use a list of object value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.
```

Sample value from `terraform.tfvars` file:

```
sample_variable = [ 
  { name = "api_key"
    type = "string"
    value = "<sensitve_api_key_value>"
    secure = true 
  }, 
  { name = "other_variable"
    type = "string"
    value = "test_value_and_might_be_sensitive" 
  } 
]
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `var.sample_variable` that you have? Or you are using default value of `[]`?

Comment: @Marcin The variable value passed from my `terraform.tfvars` looks something like below:
```
sample_variable = [
  {
    name   = "api_key",
    type   = "string"
    value  = "<sensitve_api_key_value>"
    secure = true
  },
  {
    name  = "other_variable",
    type  = "string"
    value = "test_value_and_might_be_sensitive"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please update the question with properly formatted new code.

Comment: @Marcin Could you please guide what needs to be updated in the question as I have added the brief information about the input variable definition from the `variables.tf` and its usage in my `main.tf` already. 
I have also added the sample value in the above answer.

Comment: Please add `sample_variable = [ { name = "api_key", type = "string" value = "<sensitve_api_key_value>" secure = true }, { name = "other_variable", type = "string" value = "test_value_and_might_be_sensitive" } ]` to the question, not to the comments.

Comment: @Marcin Thank you. I have added the sample value to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't iterate over **sensitive** variables in dynamic blocks. The only way to make it work, is to use [nonsensitive](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/nonsensitive) (can be dangerous!):

```
for_each = nonsensitive(var.sample_variable)
```

So its up to you to decide if you really need `var.sample_variable` to be sensitive or not. If it must be sensitive, you can't dynamically create your blocks and you have to re-architect your TF code to not require such an iteration.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it seems we cannot iterate over a sensitive input variable with a `for_each` loop. Also, I could dig up some documentation around the same and have posted it below in my answer.

Comment: It can help to make a separate local variable that only maps out the values you need. In my case, I was able to remove all the sensitive info from the final collection, but I still had to use the `nonsensitive` function to tell terraform that the data in the for_each was not the sensitive items. That is probably possible for the collection in the question if the foreach was done as an index of the original values, then load the values during the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Terraform documentation for [limitations](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#limitations-on-values-used-in-for_each) of `for_each` loop, it seems we cannot iterate over sensitive input variables.

> Sensitive values, such as sensitive input variables, sensitive outputs, or sensitive resource attributes, cannot be used as arguments to for_each. The value used in for_each is used to identify the resource instance and will always be disclosed in UI output, which is why sensitive values are not allowed. Attempts to use sensitive values as for_each arguments will result in an error.

This [terraform GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/29744) describes the problem we are encountering with the aforementioned requirement.